# Why is my 'result' variable not being correctly defined by my if...else statement?

Tags: javascript, variables, if-statement

I wish to define the variable 'result' with an if-else statement.

```
// These variables will be used to test my if statement: 
var a = 10;
var b = 20;

// My if if statement here: 
var result; 
if (a < b) {   
    console.log('a is smaller'); 
} else {
    console.log('a is not smaller'); 
}

// This will log my result to the console: 
console.log(result);
```

My if-else statement is executing correctly, but I am having trouble defining the 'result' variable.

Comment: please add the code in one piece.

Comment: Use four spaces for format code.  Use `>` to format quotes.  See the help center for more formatting help.

Comment: You never set result....

Comment: As in any language, to see some value in the variable, you need to assign it to the variable. result = 'something'. Otherwise, it's 'undefined' in js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign the string to `result` then log at the end.

```
var result;

if (a < b) {
  result = "a is smaller";
}
else {
  result = "a is not smaller";
}

console.log(result);
```

You could also use a ternary operator and template literal for conciseness:

```
var result = `a is ${a < b ? "" : "not "}smaller`;
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Assigning the string to result, rather than console.logging did the trick!

Comment: No problem @KarenKinsella, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var a = 10; var b = 20;
var result; 
if (a < b) {
    result = 'a is smaller';
} else { 
    result = 'a is not smaller'; 
}
console.log(result);
```

Or simply

```
var a = 10; var b = 20;
var result = a < b ?  'a is smaller' : 'a is not smaller'; 
console.log(result);
```

Or this if you want to just print

```
var a = 10; var b = 20;
console.log(a < b ?  'a is smaller' : 'a is not smaller');
```